# How to programmatically convert a .cal file to a .cg4?

Tags: c#, rename

In windows explorer I am able to just change the file extension of a .cal file to a .cg4 file. When I do it I get a warning; "changing the file extension might render the file useless, do you still wish to change?" or something like that (OS not in english), but if I click "yes" it works.

But trying to do this programmatically with C# doesn't work. I get an error that states: "The given path's format is not supported."

I'm using File.Move for renaming/converting and that's where the error occurs.

```
File.Move(directory + fileNameWithoutExtension + ".cal", directory + fileNameWithoutExtension + ".cg4");
```

What can I do?

Comment: Please tell us the values of `directory` and `fileNameWithoutExtension`. One or both is likely to contain one or more illegal characters.

Comment: Have you tried to move the file without changing the extension?

Comment: Note that you are only *renaming* the file, you aren't changing (converting) it.

Comment: Does the value of `directory` end in a `\\`? Or in other words: is "directory + filenameWithoutExtension + extension" a legal filename?

Comment: @ Richard Cook - yes, I checked and fileNameWithoutExtension actually had the path to it in it. Such a simple mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does this work?

```
var pathSource = System.IO.Path.Combine(directory, fileNameWithoutExtension, ".cal");
var pathDest = System.IO.Path.Combine(directory, fileNameWithoutExtension, ".cg4");
File.Move(pathSource, pathDest);
```

if it also throws an error, check if

> fileNameWithoutExtension

already contains the data of

> directory

Comment: Spot on. it contained the data of directory.